# Replacement for GuzzleHttp\UriTemplateFactory?

Tags: php, magento, guzzle

I have a plugin (for Magento 2.4.4), it is using the following class "GuzzleHttp\UriTemplateFactory" but "UriTemplateFactory" is deprecated and removed from Guzzle. Looking for a replacement. See code:

```
use GuzzleHttp\ClientFactory;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ResponseFactory;
use Taxamo\Tax\Logger\Debug\Logger as DebugLogger;
use Taxamo\Tax\Logger\Error\Logger;
use Taxamo\Tax\Model\Api\Body\CalculateTax;
use Taxamo\Tax\Model\Config;
use Taxamo\Tax\Model\Api\Entity\Address;
use GuzzleHttp\UriTemplateFactory;

class CalculateTaxService extends AbstractService
{
    const API_REQUEST_ENDPOINT = 'seller/tax/calculate';
    protected Body\CalculateTax $calculateTaxBody;

    /**
     * CalculateTaxService constructor.
     * @param ClientFactory $clientFactory
     * @param ResponseFactory $responseFactory
     * @param Config $config
     * @param Logger $errorLogger
     * @param DebugLogger $debugLogger
     * @param CalculateTax $calculateTaxBody
     */
    public function __construct(
        ClientFactory $clientFactory,
        ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        UriTemplateFactory $uriTemplateFactory,
        Config $config,
        Logger $errorLogger,
        DebugLogger $debugLogger,
        CalculateTax $calculateTaxBody
    ) {
        parent::__construct($clientFactory, $responseFactory, $uriTemplateFactory, $config, $errorLogger, $debugLogger);
        $this->calculateTaxBody = $calculateTaxBody;
    }
```

Comment: then install older version of guzzle

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that is impossible with Magento 2.4.4 as this version is required. I am in progress of using GuzzleHttp\UriTemplate but still getting some issues such as:

`code`Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\UriTemplate\UriTemplate::create()

Comment: you can write it to issues of github repo of guzzle

Comment: @bhucho actually their support page pointed me to here with using the guzzle tag

Comment: what is your github issue link?